# Prevent <input> from triggering <label> click in Safari

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap, safari

I'm working with bootstrap on a checkout process page (see code below).

In chrome everything works right:

1. Click the top option (they are payment options)
2. Select your bank from the  dropdown
3. Click the 'next' button (in this case "verder")

In Safari however:

1. Click the top option
2. Select your bank
3. Accordion collapses! Can't continue.

I found out that safari sees clicking a linked `<label>` as if you click the `<input>`.

I have absolutely no clue how to fix this. I messed with `e.preventDefault()`; without luck.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

A fiddle with the code: http://jsfiddle.net/7msd25rk/

EDIT: Fiddle instead of code

Comment: It would help if you posted the code to an online editor such as codepen.io etc - then we can help you much faster

Comment: Can you create a jsfiddle?

Comment: Thanks for the fast response guys, Here's the fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/7msd25rk/